# How does start find applications that are not in %PATH%?

Tags: path, cmd.exe

Firefox is not in my %PATH%, so

```
c:\> where firefox
```

tells me, that firefox isn't found, nor does

```
c:\> firefox
```

start the browswer.

However, if I type

```
c:\>start firefox
```

Windows (or cmd.exe) is able to locate the executable. How is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The start command does not rely only on the information in `%PATH%`. In particular, it also looks for a registry key which lists known applications, namely `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\` as well as `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\`.